# How to capture KeyboardEvent "Ctrl + C" but not KeyboardEvent "C"?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a `@HostListener` that listens to `document:keydown` events like the following

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
selectHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  switch (event.key) {
    case 'n':
      this.useNode();
      break;
    case 'c':
      this.useConnector();
      break;
    case 'd':
      this.useDefault();
      break;
    case 'g':
      this.useGrip();
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

The problem is that I also have a handler for **Copy** operation which is achieved using **Ctrl + C**, and when I press **Ctrl + C** my object gets copied, but this also triggers `case 'c'` in my code.

The question is how do I detect pressing "**Ctrl + C**" alone but not "**C**"?

Comment: There is a `ctrlKey` boolean property on that `event` object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `KeyboardEvent` contains the property `KeyboardEvent.ctrlKey`. More details can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent).